# How to create Path variable in Android.bp file to link libraries in prebuilt directory AOSP source code

Tags: android, makefile, android-source, path-variables, prebuild

I am trying to create a path variable for prebuilt libraries in Android.bp file. these libraries are placed in **/prebuilts/sdk/current/androidx/m2repository/androidx/room/room-common/2.3.0-alpha02/** and Android.bp is in other directory. how can i create link for prebuilt in android.bp file to access libraries.

Comment: Please share what you tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my answer, link below path in Android.bp file.
i wanted to access header files inside glm.glm.hpp and it was in device/genric/vulkan-cereal/include location, so below solution worked for me.

include_dirs: [
"device/generic/vulkan-cereal/include"]

as earlier my lib location was prebuilt for room-common libraries later I changed and
if it was in prebuilt directory also we can provide prebuilt directory path instead of above path